# Algolia: What happens if I import records, that have different properties, into an index?

Tags: import, record, algolia

For example, if i send recordOne with the property "color" but with the property "price". Then the second record in the set, recordTwo, has the property "price" but not the property "color".

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that both records are indexed :)

Indices are schemaless, so you have no obligation to push only records with identical attributes to the same index.

It will have some consequences though, depending on your index configuration.
If your index `attributesToIndex` parameter includes the `color` attribute, then your *recordOne* record will be searchable using that attribute, whereas the *recordTwo* record won't.

The engine will just ignore missing attributes on objects and use what's available.
Let's say you have an index containing those two objects:

```
[{
  "objectID": "recordOne",
  "name": "Colorful object",
  "color": "green",
  "price": 19.99
},

{
  "objectID": "recordTwo",
  "name": "Colorless object",
  "price": 25
}]
```

With `attributesToIndex = ['name', 'color']`
... and you perform a search query with "green".

Only *recordOne* will be returned as 'green' matched in the `color` attribute.

If you now query for "object", both records will be returned as this word is present in both records in the `name` property.

You can actually test this by yourself in Algolia's dashboard!

- Create a new index
- Use the "add manually" button to add both records (just copy the JSON above)
- Add `name` and `color` to the *attributes to index* settings in the "ranking" tab
- go back to the "browse" tab and try your queries there :)

Comment: I have a follow up question: How can I search for the record that has no color attribute?

Comment: It's hard to use a search engine to find something that "is not" ^^
Best solution here is to have a special value like "none", "transparent", ... something that means "no color" on which you can actually facet!

Comment: Or use a "no_color" tag (in _tags) in order not to mess with the faceting on the color attribute

Comment: @OlivierLance is this kind of search still impossible? I have an index of users where we add sometimes properties: I would like to find people with an empty value or no value for a new property without updating all users for my index every times we add a property. Any suggestion? :-)

Comment: @syl.fabre the way to go would be to make sure you use objectID values that are DB IDs on your side, so that when you add an attribute to a user on your side you can easily send a partial update to Algolia.
Feel free to send your question on SO or on our own community forum to have more details! https://discourse.algolia.com/